# Changing url of background image

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm doing this interface where I have a lot of buttons that are just a li with a background image  like this

```css
#menu ul.icons li.nove {
    background-image:url(images/edit-menu/icons/undo.png);
    background-size:contain;
    display:block;
    margin-top:29px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="icons"> 
<li class="um"></li>
    <li class="dois"></li>
    <li class="tres"></li>
    <li class="quatro"></li>
    <li class="cinco"></li>
<li class="seis"></li>
    <li class="sete"></li>
    <li class="oito"></li>
    <li class="nove"></li>
    <li class="dez"></li>
</ul>
```

I need to create a code where I change the background image of the button when the user clicks it, to show that button its activated, I just need to change `url(images/edit-menu/icons/` to `url(images/edit-menu/select/` and keep the same filename. I need a way to do this dynamically so I won't have to do it for each of the 10 buttons.

Hope I was clear, thanks in advance

Comment: Is this "dynamic" as in it changes after the page has loaded, or "dynamic" as in "I've never heard of Find and Replace"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you can simply do it with something like this (in jQuery, not tested):

```
$("#menu ul.icons li").click(function(){
    $(this).css('background-image', $(this).css('background-image').replace('icons', 'select'));
});
```

Edit: I just figured out a nicer way if you're using jQuery >= 1.4.

```
$("#menu ul.icons li").click(function(){
    $(this).css('background-image', function(index, oldValue){
        return oldValue.replace('icons', 'select');
    });
});
```

Comment: I got this to work by changing it a little bit `$("#menu ul.icons li").click(function(){
   var urlicon = $(this).css('background-image').replace('icons', 'selected');
 $(this).css('background-image', urlicon)
});`

Comment: Now I just need to make it when I click another button the previous selected one comes back to "icons" url

Comment: You should take a look at my answer, i made it for you. You can combine this with mine. Good luck!

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure what do you mean with the `button`, but you can try this:

```
$('.nove').click(function(){
   $(this).css('background-image', 'url(images/edit-menu/select/undo.png)');
})
```

Comment: @jsalonen, isn't it the same answer as yours? You deserve an upvote for guts.

Answer (score 2):

You could just modify css via DOM. Example with jQuery:

```
$('li.nove').click(function() {
    $(this).css('background-image', 'url(images/edit-menu/icons/icon2.png)');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm assumig you mean each one has a different image so you want to just change the path.

```
$('.icons').on('click', 'li', function(){
   var filename = $(this).css('background-image').split('/');
   filename = filename[filename.length - 1];
   filename = filename.substr(0, filename.length - 1);
   $(this).css('background-image', 'url(images/edit-menu/select/' + filename + ')');
});
```

This takes the background image and splits it up delimited by '/' then takes the last one of those minus one character which would be the `)` and returns that as the filename. Then uses that to change the background image.

[Here's a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/37ut4/1/). There's no actual images, but you can view the source in firebug or webkit inspector to see it working.

Comment: I think this code will get me where I want to, but it is not working yet, I added console.log(filename) to the end of it and it returns ')', logging $(this).css('background-image') shows that the url hasn't changed

Comment: @JoãoPedro I updated it a couple times because, well, I was wrong. What is there right now (and in the fiddle) works for me.

Comment: I also need it to when the user clicks another button the one that was selected changes to unselected. It needs to work like a tools panel of any program, like photoshop, etc.

Comment: I've got you halfway there. Use this as a learning opportunity and try to get the rest of the way. If you can't, post the code you've tried and we can go from there. I'm not here to write the whole thing for you :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```
var btn = document.getElementById('buttonID');
btn.onclick = function() {
   for (var i = 0, i < document.getElementsByTagName('li').length; i++) {
     if (this.className === 'nove') {
        document.getElementsByTagName('li')[i].style.background = 'url('+ new path +')';
     }
   }
};
```